# Can I apply for a Canadian study Visa with an expired passport with assurance that I would get a renewed passport before I'm required to travel?

Tags: canada, student-visa, passports

I cannot renew my passport early enough to meet the visa application deadline.
Can I apply for study permit to Canada with an expired passport with guarantee of a new one before I'm required to travel?

Comment: If you pay enough money and go to the right places it is almost always possible to have a passport renewed in a few days.

Answer (score 3):

No.

“When applying for your study permit, you and each family member who comes with you to Canada must have a valid passport”.

Canada can’t issue you a study permit that is valid past the expiry date of your passport.

Source: https://www.canada.ca/en/immigration-refugees-citizenship/services/study-canada/study-permit/get-documents.html